# Skype4comlib How to get Friends Displayed names

Tags: vb.net, skype, skype4com

Im in trouble getting the Displayed names of my Friends

Example: My Skype Username (Where you can add me is admin.123)

But i want to get the Displayed name Ex. (XXXX_TH3_Ad"min:_opdnsw2XXXXX)

If want to put these names in a ComboBox, If you can, write in VB.net

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), most notably [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you tried `User.DisplayName`?

Comment: I want to get the Names of my friends

Comment: We know what you want, but you have to do something on your own. Stack Overflow is generally not a coding service.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get the Display names of all your friends

```
For Each u As User in Skype.Friends.OfType<SKYPE4COMLib.User>()
        Dim name As String = u.DisplayName
Next
```